# Template class return type? how is this written?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template classes, the first is:

```
template <typename T>
class LL_iterator
{...};
```

and :

```
template <class T>
class LL
{...}
```

Now, the issue is that I am trying to write a function declaration within the 'LL' class that has a 'LL_iterator' return type. The function inside of the 'LL' class looks like this:

```
LL_iterator<T> begin();
```

The errors I am receiving are the following:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\users\vismark1994\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project 4\project 4\ll.h 103 1   Project 4

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\vismark1994\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project 4\project 4\ll.h 103 1   Project 4

Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\users\vismark1994\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project 4\project 4\ll.h 103 1   Project 4

Error   4   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation c:\users\vismark1994\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project 4\project 4\ll.h 103 1   Project 4
```

Below are the complete class declarations:

```
template <class T>
class LL
{
private:
    int count;
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    void copyList(const LL<T> &listToCopy);

public:
    LL();
    LL(const LL<T> &otherLL);
    ~LL();
    void push_back(T);
    void push_front(T);
    void pop_back();
    void clear();
    int size() const;
    T& at(int ndx);
    T& operator[] (int ndx);
    T& at(int ndx) const;
    T& operator[] (int ndx) const;
    const LL& operator=(const LL<T> & rhsObj);

    LL_iterator<T> begin();  // <-- this is where problem is 
};

template <typename T>
class LL_iterator
{

private:
    Node<T> *current;

public:
    LL_iterator();
    LL_iterator(Node<T> *ptr);
    T& operator*(); 
    LL_iterator operator++(); 
    bool operator==(const LL_iterator &rhsObj) const;
    bool operator!=(const LL_iterator &rhsObj) const;

}; //END class LL_iterator
```

I'm simply not sure how to write the function declaration for such a function (a function that returns a template type).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Please format your code. Don't ignore the live preview feature.

Comment: Move `LL_iterator` template definition up to before `LL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to, at the very least, declare the `LLIterator` template before you define the `LL` class to be able to use it in the declaration of a member function.  Where you first refer to `LLIterator<T>`, the name  `LLIterator` is not known to the compiler.

Comment: The LLiterator class was defined after the LL class, thus the compiler didn't recognize the datatype. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a class template without defining it, just like you can with classes, functions and variables:

```
template <typename> class Bar;

template <typename T> class Foo
{
    inline Bar<T> DoSomething();   // "inline" now has to be explicit
};

template <typename T> class Bar
{
    Foo<T> DoAnotherThing()        // implicitly "inline"
    {
        // implementation, may use Foo<T> as complete
    }
};

template <typename T>
Bar<T> Foo<T>::DoSomething()
{
   // implementation, now Bar<T> is complete, too
}
```

That way you can complete the definitions of mutually dependent class templates (since member function return and parameter types do not need to be complete at the point of declaration of the member function), and you can add member function definitions later.